# REINFORCE implementation does not train

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement vanilla REINFORCE algorithm for cartpole. In order to understand the concept, I did an implementation which is straightforward with no much optimization. However, the training does not increase the reward, instead it reduces. Although I have made the required sign switch to use loss function for reward. In addition, it seems to saturate when compared with a another working implementation.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.distributions.categorical import Categorical
import gym
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box
from torch.optim import Adam

def create_policy_nn(observations_size, action_size, hidden_layer_sizes, activation=nn.Tanh, output_activation=nn.Identity):    
    layers = []

    # first layer
    layers.append(nn.Linear(observations_size, hidden_layer_sizes[0]))
    layers.append(activation())

    # hidden layers
    hidden_layer_count = len(hidden_layer_sizes)
    for i in range(hidden_layer_count):        
        if i != hidden_layer_count - 1:
            layers += [(nn.Linear(hidden_layer_sizes[i], hidden_layer_sizes[i + 1])), activation()]
        else: 
            layers += [(nn.Linear(hidden_layer_sizes[i], action_size)), output_activation()] 
    
    policy_net = nn.Sequential(*layers)
    print(policy_net)
    return policy_net

def get_action(policy, observation):
    action_logits = policy(torch.as_tensor(observation, dtype=torch.float32))
    distribution = Categorical(logits=action_logits)
    return distribution.sample().item()

def get_trail_log_probability(policy, observations, actions):
    observations_tensor = torch.as_tensor(observations, dtype=torch.float32)
    actions_tensor = torch.as_tensor(actions, dtype=torch.float32)

    #print(observations_tensor)
    #print(actions_tensor)    
    actions_logits = policy(observations_tensor)
    
    # print("========================================")
    # print(observations_tensor)
    # print(actions_logits)

    distributions = Categorical(logits=actions_logits)    

    # print(distributions)
    # print(distributions.log_prob(actions_tensor))
    # print("________________________________________")
    
    return torch.sum(distributions.log_prob(actions_tensor), 0)


def run_episode(policy, environment, observations, actions, rewards):

    trail_observations = []
    trail_rewards = []
    trail_acions = [] 

    observation = environment.reset()
    observations.append(observation)

    while True:
        action = get_action(policy, observation)
        observation, reward, done, _ = environment.step(action)        

        trail_observations.append(observation)
        trail_rewards.append(reward)
        trail_acions.append(action)

        if done or len(trail_observations) == 50:          
            total_trail_reward = sum(trail_rewards)
            trail_probability = get_trail_log_probability(policy, trail_observations, trail_acions)

            # print("total trail reward " + str(total_trail_reward))
            # print("total trail log probability " + str(trail_probability))

            return torch.as_tensor(trail_probability * total_trail_reward), total_trail_reward, len(trail_acions)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
    policy = create_policy_nn(env.observation_space.shape[0], env.action_space.n, [32])   

    observations = []
    actions = []
    rewards = []

    optimizer = Adam(policy.parameters(), lr=1e-2)

    EPISODES_PER_EPOCH = 500
    TOTAL_EPOCHS = 100   

    for epoch in range(TOTAL_EPOCHS):

        loss_fun = torch.empty(EPISODES_PER_EPOCH, 1)
        rewards = torch.empty(EPISODES_PER_EPOCH, 1)
        episode_lengths = torch.empty(EPISODES_PER_EPOCH, 1)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        for episode in range(EPISODES_PER_EPOCH):     
            # print("episode " + str(episode))   
            loss_for_episode, reward_for_episode, episode_len = run_episode(policy, env, observations, actions, rewards)
            # print(loss_for_episode)
            loss_fun[episode] = -1 * loss_for_episode
            rewards[episode] = reward_for_episode
            episode_lengths[episode] = episode_len

        loss_fun_scaler = loss_fun.mean();
        print(epoch)
        print("batch loss " + str(loss_fun_scaler))
        print(rewards.sum() / EPISODES_PER_EPOCH)
        print(episode_lengths.sum() / EPISODES_PER_EPOCH)
        
        loss_fun_scaler.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        # print("Total reward is %3d after %3d epochs", loss_fun_scaler, epoch)
```